# Handling a PDF with user text strings

Tags: listings, verbatim

I am using LaTeX to generate descriptive receipts for an online system. I use special character tags and replace these with content e.g. `{{ first_name }}`. Now, there are several of these and they should all be escaped, to make sure no LaTeX code is compiled. I've tried to use the `fancyverbatim` package, but I've found `verbatim` environments don't quite line break correctly giving problems for me. Then I tried `listings`, however `listings` don't allow special characters, which is a nightmare!

TL;DR:
What can I do to escape user text strings of LaTeX code?

Comment: are there any actual latex commands in this "content"?  if not, then you can just use `\texttt{...}`, which doesn't have any of the restrictions associated with verbatim.

Comment: A user might go add latex commands, that is why they must be handled

Answer (score 4):

```
\detokenize{......}
```

Should do what you want. (If not please edit your question to have a complete document that shows the problem)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want. How can i make it allowing special characters like: æøå?

Comment: @user3062857 you should be careful what you ask for: you asked that all latex commands be disabled, and (in classic tex) `æøå` (expand to) commands to produce the required letters, so `\detokenize` breaks those. It would not in xetex or luatex as there the engine is naturally unicode and so there those letters are not special characters, they are simply normal characters.

Comment: Okay. I meant that i need an environment that only restricts not making more commands, e.g. treats everything as text, but still able to linebreak and color etc.